# Color to specific text batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a ASCII art game in batch and I'm having problems with color. I'm new to batch and I would like a simple answer.

```
    @echo off
    echo Hello
    color 01
    echo hello
    color 02
    echo hEllo
    color 03
    echo heLlo
    color 04
    echo helLo
    color 05
    echo hellO
```

This is my code I'm trying to make the text difference colors but it isn't working. If I need to be more specific I can just ask!

(I'm trying to make a game with a similar art style to dwarf fortress, If you have suggestions to a better EASY language to use 'Thank You!')

Comment: batch isn't really a language. If you are writing a game to learn batch, go on (yes, it's possible, but it's a pain; you will learn a lot that way; If you are an absolute beginner, I would suggest to start with Powershell instead of bach. It's much more powerful and already part of Windows (available for XP, built in, above XP)). If your primary goal is to write a game, better use a "real" language. Even good old BASIC would be much better than batch.

Answer (score 0):

check the [coloroutput.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/coloroutput.bat).You can use it like :

```
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 1 -b 0
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 1
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 2
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 3
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 4
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 5
call coloroutput.bat -s hello -f 0 -b 6
```

for more info - `coloroutput.bat -help`